# Would you say .Net remoting relies on tight coupling?

Tags: .net, remoting, coupling

Given that both the client and the server need to know *everything* about the object being remoted, firstly is this tight coupling, and secondly can .Net Remoting work in any other way?

Comment: "both the client and the server need to know everything about the object being remoted": no, they don't. They only need to know the interface to the object, not the concrete implementation.

Comment: @Thomas - you should have left this as an answer, as the question is about coupling as well as remoting.  So does this mean that I can create an interface in assembly I, then create a concrete class in assembly C, referencing and implementing I, and offering it through remoting, consume it in application Z with only a reference to I?  Does this structure then represent loose coupling?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's usually how solutions based on remoting are implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really answering your question, but if you want to loosen the coupling, you might look at WCF's NETTCP binding as an alternative. The client can create a proxy for the entities - this way you won't need to share any assemblies (notably Entities) between client and server.

Comment: Thanks for this, I knew WCF would be able to make some improvements