# Objects in AppDomain getting Garbage Collected

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, appdomain

I am trying to implement a plugin framework in C# where each plugin is loaded in its own `AppDomain`. I am having issues where the it seems that the remoting layer between `AppDomains` is garbage collecting my plugin instances. Each plugin inherits from this class:

```
public class PluginRefObject : MarshalByRefObject{
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which I thought would give the object an infinite lifetime. However, the plugins seem to work for a little bit and then suddenly I get a `RemotingException` with an error message:

```
Object 'longhexstring.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server
```

Which, from Googling, I believe means that the GC has deleted my remote object. Do I have to do something else to keep this object alive?

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6339701/1186321

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one. The links are bad and the posted .chm files wont open

Comment: Apologies; I believe this might be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23bk23zc(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @spectacularbob I got the .chm files to open by right clicking on the file, going to properties, then clicking "Unblock". Before I did that I could see the Contents but nothing else (which is dumb, how did I get *any* info from the file if it was blocked?), but after Unblocking I could read the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that an Exception was being thrown in my plugin, causing the AppDomain to be unloaded.

It was a bit of a tricky bug though. My plugin registered a `TcpChannel` and there was a point where I wanted the `TcpChannel` disconnected via `ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel()`. Apparently the thread running the channel was still going and asynchronously threw an `ObjectDisposedException` the next time it tried to access the channel.

After Googling, it seems that there is no clean way to kill a TcpChannel and the best solution that I have found for cleaning up a channel in another `AppDomain` is just to unload the `AppDomain`