# Azure SQL Database -> Add Index -> Object '/.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a quite large table in my database, current size is `2 852,305 MB`. I can query this database quite fast using a `localdb` instance on my developer machine, around 100 ms.

[image]

However with the exact same query and data it takes a whooping **70 seconds** on  Azure SQL Database with 20 DTUs (S1)!

[image]

I was reading up on this, **TL;DR**: Using indices for the query can fix the problem.

http://capesean.co.za/fixing-slow-performance-with-azure-sql-database/

I'm using Entity Framework so I added an `Index` and tried to run `Update-Database` from `PMC` as usual.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#multiple-column-indexes

However the Index is not added, I keep getting the error `Object '/.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.`. I have read about the same error code below but given the circumstances I do not control the Lifetime of the object.

["Object has been disconnected or does not exist at the server" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339469/object-has-been-disconnected-or-does-not-exist-at-the-server-exception)

What can I do to fix this?

It is probably not a timeout issue either, both migration and `ApplicationDbContext` has bumped timeouts.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        CommandTimeout = 10000; // migration timeout
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        //Log to output
        Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

        //Prevent timeouts
        Database.CommandTimeout = 1800;
    }
    ...
```

Complete stack trace:

> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Object
>   '/2f49096e_0c2e_49d6_a7a0_7ffbe823cf87/yxyu+vuywlowzb7myk8fhrw4_7932.rem'
>   has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ToolLogger.Verbose(String
>   sql)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
>   migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass32.<ExecuteStatements>b__30()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String
>   migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations,
>   IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   Object
>   '/2f49096e_0c2e_49d6_a7a0_7ffbe823cf87/yxyu+vuywlowzb7myk8fhrw4_7932.rem'
>   has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the migration that failed looked like this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateIndex("dbo.MyTable", new[] { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3" }, name: "IX_MyIndex");
    }
```

To prevent errors in Visual Studio I ran the command `Update-Database -script`, copied the script and ran it using SQL Management Studio directly against the Azure database. Index created looked like this:

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_MyIndex] ON [dbo].[MyTable]([Column1], [Column2], [Column3])
```

This did the trick! The query took around 8 minutes to run. Performance is now similar to `localdb`:

[image]

The good thing about `Update-Database -script` is that you get correct values for `__MigrationHistory`. I could have copied these from my `localdb` but I think this is cleaner.

Running any database code will give you this error if there is a mismatch:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The model
>   backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)

Sent this question over to Microsoft so I hope they will issue a fix for it.

https://twitter.com/Ogglas/status/1063927246245822464