# FileNotFoundException when loading an assembly using AppDomain

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to **load** & **unload** assemblies that are found **outside the current app domain**. Upon reading the following threads,

1. [AppDomain.Load() fails with FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367032/appdomain-load-fails-with-filenotfoundexception)
2. [Unloading the Assembly loaded with Assembly.LoadFrom()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258160/unloading-the-assembly-loaded-with-assembly-loadfrom) <- I couldn't understand the answer from this thread
3. [Loading/Unloading assembly in different AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132649/loading-unloading-assembly-in-different-appdomain) <- I placed the target assembly folder location in the private bin path which resulted in `FileNotFoundException`

I have the following code that raises the `FileNotFoundException`.

```cs
// let's assume that the executable running this code is found at "F:\\Test.exe"

// this is the assembly I want to load
string pathToAssembly = "C:\\Documents\\hello.dll";

// copied directly from the 1st link
AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("some");     
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
assemblyName.CodeBase = pathToAssembly;
Assembly assembly = dom.Load(assemblyName); // raises FileNotFoundException
```

I checked the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-load-assemblies-into-an-application-domain
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-unload-an-application-domain

But it didn't use AppDomain to load **AND** unload from an absolute path.

Based from the 2nd link, AppDomains search for the assemblies within its current executable's directory path. Which, of course, I need to work around that because I need to load a managed library outside of the current directory.

And, for additional information, I'm on WPF using .NET framework 4.7.2

> TLDR: What do I need to change the "look" directory of the AppDomain? or what can I do to fix this?

Comment: The link you provided says the prefered way is to LOAD and give this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=net-5.0

Comment: but that's just one part of my problem. I need to load **and unload**

Comment: Try : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unload?view=net-5.0#System_AppDomain_Unload_System_AppDomain_

Comment: I would suggest you provide a full solution rather than pasting the same links I've provided. Like I said in the question, the microsoft documentation doesn't show completely how to use it. Do read the entirety of my question and problems before replying back

Comment: di you open my link and look at the example?  The title of page may look similar but the example is different.

Comment: your first link only showed how to load an assembly using `Assembly` which isn't what I want. your second link is similar to my link wherein it just created an `AppDomain` object and unloaded itself without loading any assembly. If you checked `AppDomain.Load()`, it needs either an `AssemblyName` object or the other parameters in the function overload. Then again, I *need* to get an assembly **outside** of the current executable's directory

Comment: try procmon, to find out, which file is not found, and where the code is searching